# How to intentionally expire a build in fabric.io

Tags: twitter-fabric, beta, google-fabric

I am using fabri.io beta distribution, but how can I expire all previous builds so I can force users to use latest version?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Fabric Beta builds can't be expired and it's not possible to force testers to upgrade.